# In Cmake how to update the makefiles with new source files without cleaning the object files

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake, and I just added new source files and I want to include that new source files in the cmake generated makefiles to include in the building. I tried rebuild_cache but nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your cmake file was built.  If you use GLOB,  you must run cmake manually any time you add or remove a source file.  If you explicitly list your source files, just run make again.  CMake will detect the changed CMakeLists.text.

CMake suggests the latter for this reason:

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

[CMake documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3afile)